# Renaming JSP tags with Jquery

Tags: jquery, jsp

Helping support a project that is using JSP and Jquery. Have an issue where they are naming the input boxes as if they are an array and then serializing the form as JSON. The issue is that they have a remove button on the form and it is not renaming the input boxes before submitting. The JAVA code sees this as a null row in the array. Is there some way to loop over these elements and rename(renumber) them in Jquery?

HTML

```
    <c:forEach items="${assignmentRecords}" var="assignmentRecord" varStatus="status">
                                        <tr <c:if test="${isTemplate!=0}">class="pte_row_markup"</c:if> id="${status.index }">
                                            <td><div id="pte_table_cell_outer">
                                                <div id="pte_table_cell_inner1">
                                                    <input type="hidden" name="assignmentSetGridList[${status.index}].asIndividuals" value="${fn:escapeXml(assignmentRecord.individual)}"/>
                                                    <input type="hidden" name="assignmentSetGridList[${status.index}].asIds" value="${assignmentRecord.id}"/>
                                                    <input type="hidden" name="assignmentSetGridList[${status.index}].asPrincipalIds" value="${assignmentRecord.principalId}"/>
                                                    <input type="hidden" name="assignmentSetGridList[${status.index}].asNames" value="${fn:escapeXml(assignmentRecord.name)}"/>
                                                    <span id="assignee@incrRowCnt">${fn:escapeXml(assignmentRecord.name)}</span>
                                                </div>
                                            </div></td>
                                            <td><div id="pte_table_cell_outer">
                                                <div id="pte_table_cell_inner1">
                                                    <label style="display:none;" for="roleId@incrRowCnt">Role for ${assignmentRecord.name}</label>
                                                    <select id="roleId@incrRowCnt" name="assignmentSetGridList[${status.index}].asRole" size="1" >
                                                        <c:forEach var="item" items="${assignmentRoleList}">
                                                            <c:choose><c:when test="${item.value == assignmentRecord.role}">
                                                                <option value="${item.value}" selected="selected">${item.label}</option>
                                                            </c:when><c:otherwise>
                                                                <option value="${item.value}">${item.label}</option>
                                                            </c:otherwise></c:choose>
                                                        </c:forEach>
                                                    </select>
                                                </div>
                                            </div></td>
                                            <td><div id="pte_table_cell_outer">
                                                <div id="pte_table_cell_inner1">
                                                    <label style="display:none;" for="taskTypeId@incrRowCnt">Task Type for ${assignmentRecord.name}</label>
                                                    <select id="taskTypeId@incrRowCnt" name="assignmentSetGridList[${status.index}].asTaskType" size="1" >
                                                        <c:choose><c:when test="${preferencesForm.typeIsAudit==false}">
                                                            <c:forEach var="item" items="${regAsgntTaskTypeList}">
                                                                <c:choose><c:when test="${item.value == assignmentRecord.taskType}">
                                                                    <option value="${item.value}" selected="selected">${item.label}</option>
                                                                </c:when><c:otherwise>
                                                                    <option value="${item.value}">${item.label}</option>
                                                                </c:otherwise></c:choose>
                                                            </c:forEach>
                                                        </c:when><c:otherwise>
                                                            <c:forEach var="item" items="${auditAsgstTypTaskTypMap[preferencesForm.asetName]}">
                                                                <c:choose><c:when test="${item.value == assignmentRecord.taskType}">
                                                                    <option value="${item.value}" selected="selected">${item.label}</option>
                                                                </c:when><c:otherwise>
                                                                    <option value="${item.value}">${item.label}</option>
                                                                </c:otherwise></c:choose>
                                                            </c:forEach>
                                                        </c:otherwise></c:choose>
                                                    </select>
                                                </div>
                                            </div></td>
                                            <td><div id="pte_table_cell_outer">
                                                <div id="pte_table_cell_inner1">
                                                    <!-- <div class="datePickerDecorator"> -->
                                                        <div class="uef-input uef-date-enhanced pte_overwrite1" data-uefID="uef-in-dtPkr">
                                                            <label style="display:none;" for="dateDueId@incrRowCnt">Due Date for ${assignmentRecord.name}, format m m / d d / y y y y</label>
                                                            <input id="dateDueId@incrRowCnt" name="assignmentSetGridList[${status.index}].asDueDate" type="text" class="uef-datePicker" 
                                                                        autocomplete="off"  value="${assignmentRecord.dueDate}"/>
                                                        </div>
                                                    <!-- </div> -->
                                                </div>
                                                <div id="pte_table_cell_inner2">
                                                    <p class="supportText" id=""><emac:message key="preferences.templates.edit.table.dateFormat"/></p>
                                                </div>
                                            </div></td>
                                            <td><div id="pte_table_cell_outer">
                                                <div id="pte_table_cell_inner1">
                                                    <label style="display:none;" for="timeDueId@incrRowCnt">Time Due for ${assignmentRecord.name}</label>
                                                    <select id="timeDueId@incrRowCnt" name="assignmentSetGridList[${status.index}].asTimeDue" size="1" >
                                                        <option value="">--</option>
                                                        <c:forEach var="item" items="${timeDueList}">
                                                            <c:choose><c:when test="${item.value == assignmentRecord.time}">
                                                                <option value="${item.value}" selected="selected">${item.label}</option>
                                                            </c:when><c:otherwise>
                                                                <option value="${item.value}">${item.label}</option>
                                                            </c:otherwise></c:choose>
                                                        </c:forEach>
                                                    </select>
                                                </div>
                                            </div></td>
                                            <td><div id="pte_table_cell_outer">
                                                <div id="pte_table_cell_inner4">
                                                    <div class="spellCheckerDecorator">
                                                        <div class="uef-textArea uef-input pte_overwrite1" data-uefID="uef-in-txtArea@incrRowCnt">
                                                            <label style="display:none;" for="instructionsId@incrRowCnt">Instructions for ${assignmentRecord.name}</label>
                                                            <textarea id="instructionsId@incrRowCnt" name="assignmentSetGridList[${status.index}].asInstructions" rows="5" cols="40" maxlength="800" 
                                                                    class="charCounter" >${assignmentRecord.instructions}</textarea>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div></td>
                                            <td><div id="pte_table_cell_outer">

                                                <div id="pte_table_bdcell_inner_actn">
                                                    <input type="submit" id="removeBtnId@incrRowCnt" class="overlay uef-btn pte_header_btn" 
                                                            value='<emac:message key="preferences.templates.edit.table.remove.btn"/>'  
                                                            onClick="return PteUtil.deleteThisAssigneeFromSet(this);"/>
                                                </div>
                                            </div></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </c:forEach>
```

Jquery

```
deleteThisAssigneeFromSet : function(btn, remove) {

        if( ! $(btn).parents('tr').hasClass('pte_row_markup') ) {
            $(btn).parents('tr').remove();
        }






    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can readily grab those elements and update their `name` property; see inline comments.

```
deleteThisAssigneeFromSet : function(btn, remove) {
    // Get the buttons' parent `tr` (I'd use `closest`, not `parents`)
    var parent = $(btn).closest('tr');
    if( ! parent.hasClass('pte_row_markup') ) {
        // Get the row's siblings
        var siblings = parent.siblings('tr');
        // Remove the row
        parent.remove();
        // Update the inputs in the rows, row-by-row
        siblings.each(function(i) {
            var brackets = "[" + i + "]";
            // Uses an "attribute starts with" selector to find the inputs
            $(this).find("[name^=assignmentSetGridList]").each(function() {
                this.name = this.name.replace(/\[\d+\]/, brackets);
            });
        });
    }
```

Live Example:

```js
function deleteThisAssigneeFromSet(btn, remove) {
    // Get the buttons' parent `tr` (I'd use `closest`, not `parents`)
    var parent = $(btn).closest('tr');
    if( ! parent.hasClass('pte_row_markup') ) {
        // Get the row's siblings
        var siblings = parent.siblings('tr');
        // Remove the row
        parent.remove();
        // Update the inputs in the rows, row-by-row
        siblings.each(function(i) {
            var brackets = "[" + i + "]";
            // Uses an "attribute starts with" selector to find the inputs
            $(this).find("[name^=assignmentSetGridList]").each(function() {
                this.name = this.name.replace(/\[\d+\]/, brackets);
            });
        });
    }
}
$("input[value=delete]").on("click", function() {
    deleteThisAssigneeFromSet(this);
});
```

```html
<table>
    <tr  id="IINDEXX">
        <td><div id="pte_table_cell_outer">
            <div id="pte_table_cell_inner1">
                <input type="hidden" name="assignmentSetGridList[0].asIndividuals" value=""/>
                <input type="hidden" name="assignmentSetGridList[0].asIds" value=""/>
                <input type="hidden" name="assignmentSetGridList[0].asPrincipalIds" value=""/>
                <input type="hidden" name="assignmentSetGridList[0].asNames" value=""/>
            </div>
        </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="button" value="delete">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr  id="1">
        <td><div id="pte_table_cell_outer">
            <div id="pte_table_cell_inner1">
                <input type="hidden" name="assignmentSetGridList[1].asIndividuals" value=""/>
                <input type="hidden" name="assignmentSetGridList[1].asIds" value=""/>
                <input type="hidden" name="assignmentSetGridList[1].asPrincipalIds" value=""/>
                <input type="hidden" name="assignmentSetGridList[1].asNames" value=""/>
            </div>
        </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="button" value="delete">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="2">
        <td><div id="pte_table_cell_outer">
            <div id="pte_table_cell_inner1">
                <input type="hidden" name="assignmentSetGridList[2].asIndividuals" value=""/>
                <input type="hidden" name="assignmentSetGridList[2].asIds" value=""/>
                <input type="hidden" name="assignmentSetGridList[2].asPrincipalIds" value=""/>
                <input type="hidden" name="assignmentSetGridList[2].asNames" value=""/>
            </div>
        </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="button" value="delete">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

Side note: It looks like the rows have the index as `id`s. If you want to fix them too, add this at the top of the `siblings.each` callback:

```
this.id = i;
```

Comment: *(Doh! If you don't see `replace` above, hit refresh.)*

Comment: Seem to not have worked. Still numbered odd in the DOM. Goes from [0] to [2]

Comment: Shouldnt it be something like this:deleteThisAssigneeFromSet : function(btn, remove) {
        if( ! $(btn).parents('tr').hasClass('pte_row_markup') ) {
        $(btn).parents('tr').remove();
        $(btn).closest("table").find("tr").each(function(i) {
            this.name = this.name.replace(/\[\d+\]/, "[" + i + "]");
        });
    }

Comment: @ssgtob1 - I should have been going row by row and using the row index. I've fixed it, sorry about that.

Comment: You, sir, are amazing. Works perfectly!